How to understand the way vector architecture works and the stalls? Computer Organization and Design by Patterson MIPS edition
On page 536 of Computer Organization and Design MIPS edition, it says

On the vector processor, each vector instruction will only stall for the first element in each vector, and then subsequent elements will flow smoothly down the pipeline. Thus, pipeline stalls are required only once per vector operation, rather than once per vector element.

For the example it gives, it shows the conventional MIPS code versus the vector MIPS code for

Y = a * X + Y

where X and Y are vectors of 64v double precision floating-point numbers, initially resident in memory and a is a scalar double precision variable. Assume that the starting addresses of X and Y are in $s0 and $s1 respectively
Conventional MIPS code:
loop: 
    l.d    $f0, a($sp)
    addiu  $t0, $s0, #512
    l.d    $f2, 0($s0)
    mul.d  $f2, $f2, $f0
    l.d    $f4, 0($s1)
    add.d  $f4, $f4, $f2
    s.d    $f4, 0($s1)
    addiu  $s0, $s0, #8
    addiu  $s1, $s1, #8
    subu   $t1, $t0, $s0
    bne    $t1, $zero, loop

vector MIPS code:
    l.d      $f0, a($sp)
    lv       $v1, 0($s0)
    mulvs.d  $v2, $v1, $f0
    lv       $v3, 0($s1)
    addv.d   $v4, $v2, $v3
    sv       $v4, 0($s1)

It says in this example the pipelien stall frequency on MIPS will be about 64 times higher than it is on the vector version of MIPS.
How do they get this number (64 times higher)?
I have little idea about how exactly vector processor works and how it is different than SIMD extensions like MMX, SSE and AVX.
I thought in vector architecture, there would be a large set of vector registers, and the execution units doing the actual calculations are pipelined. But I just could not connect the dots.
Insights will be greatly appreciated! TIA!

The scalar code isn't software-pipelined, or even scheduled to try to hide any load-use latency within a single iteration.  e.g. it uses every load result in the next instruction after loading. It'll stall a lot on an in-order MIPS, although I didn't try to verify the 64x number.
It also has unnecessary loop overhead (a subu and then comparing the subtraction to zero, instead of simply using bne $t0, $s0.  But wait a minute, $t0 is set to $s0 + 512 every iteration, then $s0 is incremented, so there's no way for them to ever be equal and the loop to exit.  Normally you'd just bne one of the pointers against an end-pointer.)
As they explain, the vector version doesn't have to stall every element.  It probably has to stall once, on the first element of mulvs.d, but vectorized loads were still streaming in during that stall, so the next element of the multiply can start right after the first element.  And so on for the other operations.  A cache-miss during the loading would force later elements of the multiply to stall.

Modern commercial-CPU SIMD like MMX/SSE/AVX uses short fixed-length vectors like 16, 32, or 64 bytes so software has to loop.  (Hand-written or auto-vectorized by a compiler from scalar loops).  MIPS MSA and ARM NEON / AArch64 ASIMD are the same way.  MIPS has also had the DPS extension that use GPR integer registers as 4-byte or 8-byte SIMD vectors of byte or u16.
Unlike what Patterson and Hennesy describe for a vector processor, only one instruction goes through the pipeline to control a wide execution unit, allowing high throughput without making the whole pipeline that wide.  Power/area costs for widening the whole out-of-order exec pipeline typically scale quadratically since the renamer has to check all instructions handled in a cycle against each other, and things like that.  That's less of a problem for an in-order CPU, but still more stuff has to be wider than if you just have some wide vector registers and wide execution units.
For newly-introduced SIMD extensions, or low-power CPUs, some CPUs will only have half-width execution units, e.g. AMD Bulldozer through Zen 1 decoding 256-bit AVX instructions like vaddps ymm2, ymm1, ymm0 as 2 micro-ops, like Intel did for 128-bit SSE vectors in Pentium 3 through Pentium M, and like Intel does now for its Gracemont E-cores.)  Or for example Zen 4 handles 512-bit instructions as a single uop that occupied an execution unit for 2 cycles. Intel Sandybridge / Ivy Bridge was like that for 256-bit loads/stores so data paths to/from L1d cache were only 128-bit, but had 256-bit SIMD ALUs.  See https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/ for a very well-written deep-dive on that microarchitecture.
Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide! is also worth a read; it has a section on SIMD.
Anyway, only tracking one operation through the pipeline lets it overlap well with surrounding scalar work, and lets out-of-order execution see plenty far ahead to find instruction-level parallelism across loop iterations to hide latency much better than if vpaddb ymm, ymm, ymm took 32 entries in the reorder buffer (ROB).
ARM SVE and RISC-V extension V are attempts to make software binaries future-compatible with longer HW vector lengths, with instructions like increment-pointer-by-HW-vector-length.  And per-element masking so small and/or odd-sized arrays can be handled.  (e.g. a masked store leaves memory unmodified in elements where the mask had a 0 bit, and doesn't fault if those masked elements are in unmapped pages, or without write permission.)
GPU SIMD is quite different: they keep the pipelines super simple (in-order exec) so they can just have tons of pipelines.  That makes it easier for GPUs to handle non-contiguous data; CPU SIMD does much better when a single 256-bit load from cache can pull in 8 of the same kind of element (e.g. x coordinates) that you want to work on.  Strided loads aren't a thing on most ISAs.

Thank you for the great information! It'll take me some time to read the links. "As they explain, the vector version doesn't have to stall every element. It probably has to stall once, on the first element of mulvs.d, but vectorized loads were still streaming in during that stall, so the next element of the multiply can start right after the first element." I still don't understand this. Could you explain further how this works? For example, does the stall happens during vector loading or the load-use? What exactly is the process so thst the next element can start right after the first?

@Bbbbbunn2023: The quote actually says instructions like mulvs.d will stall waiting for the first element.  But the vector load proceeds with 1/clock throughput, so in the cycle after the first element of mulvs.d starts, the second element of the load result is ready for mulvs.d to start on it.  I don't know if they picture having an "instruction" go down an in-order pipeline for every element, or if one pipeline slot triggers a multi-cycle execution unit to start operating in a way that writes one element at a time in a vector register file.
